# How do I find visitor name from his / her IP address

Tags: ip, user-tracking

While working with Google Analytics, I was thinking how do I get the name of user currently viewing my websites. I Googled and found that many Companies are providing the same & on top of that using GA, like leadfeeder, whoisvisiting etc.

So after doing more research I found a websites that provides IP's ISP full information like name, phone, email etc is https://bgp.he.net, this websites actually pull all the information related to ISP.

I again started more search using ASN number etc, but didn't got any luck. At last I came here at SO. hoping I would get good inputs from experts here.

I am eager to know the working of these companies, how they actually get those names ?

I wanted to know the Name of user or companies visiting my websites, I have no plan to buy the services from any similar services provider companies.

I know its against GDPR, but How those companies are getting the names of visitors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that sounds like its against GDPR

Comment: Hi @mast3rd3mon , is there a legal way to get those details of visitor ?

Comment: why do you need to know their name?

Comment: I have no plan to use those name for any type of business, I just want to know the tricks and workings to get those details.. Thanks Sir

Comment: then that will be against GDPR as you dont need those names

Comment: hmm, may be, but knowing how other companies are getting those names are not against any law I guess. ??

Comment: can you provide any websites which can do that?

Comment: leadfeeder.com ,whoisvisiting.com and many others also you could google it;.

Comment: if you intend to get the visitor's name and/or email in order to contact them, or anything of the sort, it is highly immoral if not illegal

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth to point out that collecting PII information about your users - via Google Analytics - is against Google Analytics policy:

*"To protect user privacy, Google policies mandate that no data be passed to Google that Google could use or recognize as personally identifiable information (PII). PII includes, but is not limited to, information such as email addresses, personal mobile numbers, and social security numbers."*

Please check more details here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Details of ISPs are publicly known, since they are allocated blocks of IP addresses which they distribute to their customers. The name of those customers are not generally known, and a single IP doesn't necessarily resolve to a single human in the first place. No, you cannot get an individual's name and address from an IP without a subpoena from a court and then requesting that information from the ISP, which knows the identity of the entity to which they allocated the IP. But a court won't grant you that unless you can show any law that IP has broken.

Comment: Thanks for your time Sir, If this is the case then how those companies like leadfeeder, whoisvisiting are showing names of visitors. Please at least give me few inputs. to satisfy myself.

Comment: Some sort of advertisement based cookie tracking, shadow profile building, and from somewhere they link actual personal information to that profile, e.g. when you enter your actual name into a form while one of their tracking scripts is embedded in the same page.

Comment: hmm, that's absolutely make sense. Thanks a lot Sir, I have at least 1 way to understand  how they get the names of visitors ... :-)